# Can you do multi-tenant Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We're currently using IdentityServer 4 with some modifications to be multi-tenant according to the OpenID Connect (OIDC) specification which has a `acr_values` query parameter.

So we pass in `&acr_values=tenant:acme` as query parameter in the URL when redirecting to the identity provider.

We want to migrate from IdentityServer 4 to Azure Active Directory (AAD). Is it possible to configure one AAD instance to be multi-tenant? Using the `acr_values` query parameter with the `tenant` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As an IdP, Azure AD is indeed multi-tenant**, however instead of targeting a tenant you target a multi-tenant app.

Regarding IdentityServer4 `acr_values` param, it's meant to be used to bypass IdP selection thus it's not needed since you only need to pass the proper `client_id` param and build the Azure AD protocol specific (OIDC/OAuth2) endpoint using a `multi-tenant id` such as `organizations` or `common`. E.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: Could you clarify? If the tenant is named "acme" then our Blazor app has `example.com/acme/` as route. We would like to use the same Azure AD instance for all our tenants so we don't have to create a new Azure AD instance for every new tenant. I don't understand what you mean by "common" or "organizations".

Comment: If you want all your accounts to be hosted in one Azure AD instance, then, from an Azure AD perspective, your application should be single tenant. An Azure AD tenant is an IdP on its own so, even if supported, a potential acr_values param would be useless if only one instance is required.

Comment: Yes, we want all accounts in one Azure AD instance, but we want the application to host many organizations so one person can have separate accounts in multiple organizations, so when Joe logs in on `example.com/acme/` he uses one password, but when he logs in on `example.com/foo` he uses another password because they're different accounts but on the same Azure AD instance.

Comment: That's only possible if Joe has one account per org. Once again, if both are hosted in 1 instance multi-tenancy at the Azure AD level is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

•   *`You cannot have one Azure AD instance for multiple tenants since tenants are subscription based and every tenant can be specified as an independent directory having its own custom domain name with verified DNS records as the authoritative start of the authority for all the user identities created in it`*. Thus, it **acts as a central authentication and authorization directory for all the identities and applications created in it**.

As a result, as of now, **only applications in an Azure AD tenant can be configured as multi-tenant, i.e., multiple tenants share the same physical instance of the app. Although tenants share physical resources (such as VMs or storage), each tenant gets its own logical instance of the app wherein application data is shared amongst the users within a tenant, but not with other tenants**.

•   Thus, since you are migrating from IdentityServer4 to Azure AD, **you must configure Azure AD as a federation IDP and configure your IdentityServer4 in that way such that when a user tries to login to a SaaS app through a user identity that is created in IdentityServer4, then he is redirected to the Azure AD for authentication purposes and accordingly token is issued and once again, he is redirected to IdentityServer4 for further application based purpose**.

To configure an application as a multi-tenant application, kindly refer to the below snapshots for reference: -

[image: Application configuration as a multi-tenant]

Also, to add **‘IdentityServer4’** as an IDP to Azure AD, kindly **ensure to add it as an ‘App Registration’ in your new Azure AD tenant** as stated below and ensure to **add the same details in your SaaS app that is configured for authentication with ‘IdentityServer4’**: -

•   *`Register your application with your new Azure Active Directory tenant by clicking on App Registrations --> Register an application --> Name: IdentityServer4 --> Accounts in any organizational directory`*

•   Then, in the **Redirect URI** field, enter the **‘callback/redirect URI’** path configured in **`IdentityServer4 for Azure AD authentication which will be like ‘http://localhost:5000/signin-aad’ which you can find it in the ‘IdentityServer4’ project in the ‘Startup’ class in the ‘ConfigureServices’ method`**.

•   Also, ensure to configure the token and redirect URI as below: -

[image: App details configured]

[image: Application registration]

This will ensure that **‘Azure AD’ is configured as an external identity provider in your application as below by configuring the correct ‘Application ID, Tenant ID, etc. correctly**. In this way, you can surely configure ‘IdentityServer4’ as an IDP in Azure AD: -

```
    services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

        options.Authority = "https://login.windows.net/<Directory (tenant) ID>";
        options.ClientId = "<Your Application (client) ID>";
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-aad";
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-aad";
        options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-aad";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
    });
```

Please find the below link for more detailed clarification on this: -

***https://www.ashleyhollis.com/how-to-configure-azure-active-directory-with-identityserver4***

***https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html***

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use IdentityServer4 anymore, our goal is to migrate away from it, and not use it anymore. We want to use Azure AD instead.

Comment: Since, you said to use Azure AD in multi-tenant mode, that's why I suggested this to you. Btw, you can create all your user identities in Azure AD according to IdentityServer4 as in existing and then you can create 'Application Registrations' in multi-tenant mode accordingly.

Comment: No, I never said I use Azure in multi-tenant mode, we don't even use Azure AD at all. I was wondering if it would be possible for me to use Azure AD and have all the tenants in the same Azure AD.

Comment: No, it is not possible to have all the tenants in the same Azure AD as every tenant has its own Azure AD and it represents the IAM facilities for the resources deployed in that tenant.

Comment: We want that every time a customer signs up for an account they become a tenant in the application.

Answer (score 0):

if all your tenants are with azure ad, then yes, you can have a multi-tenant app registration to login your users from multiple azure ad tenants.